# Correct way of dispatching multiple async action in Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I was wondering what would be the correct way of dispatching multiple async actions of similar types. I have a homepage which has four different `<Thumbnail />` components.

- The `<Thumbnail />` components shows movie listing. Like 1st will show 
  Top Rated Movies, 2nd will show UpComing movies and so on. The API endpoints are almost the same except there is a difference in query params.
- I have made a single action creator as endpoints are almost same. As far as dispatching actions is concerned, I'm not sure whether I should iterate over the list of endpoint and dispatch 4 different actions?
- Or should I dispatch and only one action and inside the action creator I'll iterate over the urls.

Any help will be appreciated.

Approach 1

**Homepage.js**

```
    componentDidMount() {
      this.categories = [{
        title: "Top Rated Movies",
        url: "movie/top_rated",
      },
      {
        title: "Now Playing",
        url: "movie/now_playing"
      },
      {
        title: "Upcoming Movies",
        url: "movie/upcoming"
      },
      {
       title: "Top Rated TV shows",
       url: "tv/popular",
     }]
     this.categories.forEach(({ url ) => {
       this.props.getFeaturedMovies(url)
     })
    }
```

**Action.js**

```
    export const getFeaturedMovies = (url) => {
      return async (dispatch) => {
        dispatch({ type: REQUEST_ALL_FEATURED_MOVIES })
        fetch(`https://api.themoviedb.org/3/${url}?api_key=${API_KEY}`)
          .then(res => res.json())
          .then(data => dispatch({ type: RECEIVE_ALL_FEATURED_MOVIES, title, payload: data, success: true }))
          .catch(error => {
          dispatch({ type: RECEIVE_ALL_FEATURED_MOVIES, payload: error, success: false })
           })
        }
    };
```

**Approach 2**

**Homepage.js**

```
    componentDidMount() {
        this.categories = [{
          title: "Top Rated Movies",
          url: "movie/top_rated",
        },
        {
          title: "Now Playing",
          url: "movie/now_playing"
        },
        {
          title: "Upcoming Movies",
          url: "movie/upcoming"
        },
        {
          title: "Top Rated TV shows",
          url: "tv/popular",
        }]
        this.props.getFeaturedMovies(this.categories)
      }
```

**Action.js**

```
    export const getFeaturedMovies = (categories) => {
      return async (dispatch) => {
        dispatch({ type: REQUEST_ALL_FEATURED_MOVIES })
        let featuredMovies = categories.map(async ({ title, url }) => {
          let data = await fetch(`https://api.themoviedb.org/3/${url}?api_key=${API_KEY}`)
          let response = await data.json()
          return {title, data: response.results}
        })
        let featuredMoviesList = await Promise.all(featuredMovies)
        dispatch({ type: RECEIVE_ALL_FEATURED_MOVIES, payload: featuredMoviesList, success: true })
      }
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

I think for now the best approach is the second one since it'll be easier to handle the loading state (you will get a consistent loading state for all the fetches, instead of several separate spinners).

This might be different in the future once we get AsyncMode, but for now I'd recommend this.

Comment: but the page load time is gonna be more as we are waiting for all the promises to be settled.

Comment: Yes, that's something that can happen. However, you have to take into account actual performance vs perceived performance. If you sprinkle lots of spinners around the page it makes it feel slower than it actually is, and it may _feel_ faster if you take a few more ms to complete the calls and show them all at once (UI development is more art than science sometimes). Ultimately, it depends a lot on how heavy these calls are.